# making cookie with 'path=localhost' not shared across subdomains

Tags: cookies, subdomain, blazor-webassembly, shared

I have four subdomains in my site three of them: en.localhost:44367, de.localhost:44367 and fr.localhost:44367.

when I set a cookie with path=localhost, this is not created and I still get the cookie with the path: en.localhost or others ...

and the cookie is not shared across subdomains, I can verify this in the browser F12
tools.

so how to make a shared cookie that can be shared between all 4 subdomains as 'localhost' but not en.localhost or .. others.